# Postgres Standard deviation of multiple columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to calculate the standard deviation of multiple columns for each given ID.

I have a table that shows gives me demand over time and I need to calculate volatility of the demand.

```
SELECT id ::Text, n0 ::numeric, n1 ::numeric, n2 ::Numeric, n3 ::numeric, n4 ::numeric, n5 ::numeric, n6 ::numeric, n7 ::numeric  
FROM mytable
```

I would like to add another column that calculates the standard deviation from the values in in columns `n0-n7` for each `id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [stddev_samp](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-aggregate.html)? Or do you mean the standard deviation **between** columns? If so, take a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23596515/aggregate-functions-across-multiple-columns-in-postgres).

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm.  Probably the easiest way is to unpivot the table and re-aggregate.  For instance:

```
select id, stddev(n)
from ((select id, n0 as n from mytable) union all
      (select id, n1 as n from mytable) union all
      (select id, n2 as n from mytable) union all
      (select id, n3 as n from mytable) union all
      (select id, n4 as n from mytable) union all
      (select id, n5 as n from mytable) union all
      (select id, n6 as n from mytable) union all
      (select id, n7 as n from mytable)
     ) t
group by id;
```

Note:  you can choose between `stddev_pop()` or `stddev_samp()`.  The latter would be the typical choice for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

To use [`stddev_pop()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-aggregate.html) aggregate function you should gather the values into an array and next `unnest()` the array:

```
select id, stddev_pop(val)
from (
    select id, unnest(array[n0, n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7]) val
    from mytable
    ) sub
group by id;
```