# Postgres Functions Across Columns

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions, calculated-columns

I've got unstacked data in a Postgres database, trying to perform calculations across columns.

Here's my data:

| group | obs1 | obs2 | obs3 | obs4 | obs5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 74.030 | 74.002 | 74.019 | 73.992 | 74.008 |
| 2 | 73.995 | 73.992 | 74.001 | 74.011 | 74.004 |
| 3 | 73.988 | 74.024 | 74.021 | 74.005 | 74.002 |
| 4 | 74.002 | 73.996 | 73.993 | 74.015 | 74.009 |

Trying to get the average and range (Max()-Min()) across columns.
Below is the desired outcome:

```
| group | obs1  |  obs2 |  obs3 | obs4  | obs5|grp_avg| grp_range|
|:-----:|:-----:|:-----:|:-----:|:-----:|:-----:|:-----:|:------:|
|1      |74.030 | 74.002| 74.019| 73.992| 74.008| 74.010| 0.038 |
|2      |73.995 | 73.992| 74.001| 74.011| 74.004| 74.001| 0.019 |
|3      |73.988 | 74.024| 74.021| 74.005| 74.002| 74.008| 0.036 |
|4      |74.002 | 73.996| 73.993| 74.015| 74.009| 74.003| 0.022 |
```

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23596515/aggregate-functions-across-multiple-columns-in-postgres) question and don't understand, but don't believe it solves this. Based on that question it pointed to Postgres [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/xaggr.html) but it seems way more complicated than I am looking to do.

In a `Pandas DataFrame` (how I'm doing this now) there is the option of changing the `axis` parameter, causing functions to work on columns rather than rows.  I'm hopeful Postgres has some kind of similar functionality.

Comment: No, you don't need a custom aggregate function. `SELECT *, (SELECT avg(val) FROM unnest(ARRAY[obs1, obs2, obs3, obs4, obs5]) val) AS grp_avg FROM my_table` will do.

Comment: But yes, storing data in a non-normalised form will require queries that are slightly more complicated than `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, the quoted accepted solution answers your question. To understand it better, it can be represented with a [common table expression.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) This has the advantage that the query is created step by step and you can check the results at each stage (see [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/UqA6ou7T)).

```sql
with one_column as (
    select 
        grp, 
        unnest(array[obs1, obs2, obs3, obs4, obs5]) as elem
    from my_table
),
aggs as (
    select 
        grp, 
        avg(elem)::numeric(20, 3), 
        max(elem)- min(elem) as rng
    from one_column
    group by grp
)
select 
    grp, 
    obs1, obs2, obs3, obs4, obs5,
    avg, 
    rng
from aggs
join my_table using(grp)
order by grp;
```

Alternatively, you can just calculate the aggregates using the functions [greatest() and least().](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-GREATEST-LEAST)

```sql
select 
    grp, obs1, obs2, obs3, obs4, obs5,
    ((obs1+ obs2+ obs3+ obs4+ obs5)/ 5)::numeric(20, 3) as avg,
    greatest(obs1, obs2, obs3, obs4, obs5)- least(obs1, obs2, obs3, obs4, obs5) as rng
from my_table;
```

[Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/vrBBsvUe)

Comment: Your 'about' section quote is the funniest thing I've read in a while!

Comment: Step by step CTE in db<>fiddle was helpful to understand - thank you!